# paragraph over 2 columns in an article document

Tags: tables, paragraphs

I have a two column format for an article and a small paragraph which i want to split in those 2 columns(hard break). I dont want to use \vfill, as I am intending to display a table after the paragraph.
Any ideas how to do it?

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}    
\usepackage{lipsum}    
\usepackage{supertabular}    
%\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float    
%\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}    
%\makeatother    

\begin{document}    
\twocolumn[]    
\lipsum[1-1]    
\begin{table*}[ht]    
\caption{Caption}    
\center    
\begin{supertabular}{c c c c c}    
\hline \hline    
A & B & C & D & E\\    
\hline    
1 & a & A & D & E \\     
2 & b & B & D & E\\    
3 & c & C & D & E\\    
4 & d & D & D & E\\    
5 & e & E & D & E\\    
6 & f & F & D & E\\    
7 & g & G & D & E\\    
8 & g & G & D & E\\    
9 & g & G & D & E\\    
10 & g & G & D & E\\    
11& g & G & D & E\\    
12 & g & G & D & E\\    
13 & g & G & D & E\\    
14 & g & G & D & E\\    
\hline    
\end{supertabular}    
\end{table*}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any code you can show us? Document class? Other relevant packages loaded?

Comment: your question is not very clear, in particluar if you add the table, why does it not break in the correct place automatically? But `\pagebreak` possibly does what you want

Comment: I don't understand your question, but maybe the [multicol-package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) offers some support for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, in a `twocolumn` document, you want the paragraph in 2 columns directly followed by the table, which spreads across both columns (is 'wide' due to the `*`).

If that's right, then you have to contend with the following limitation: in two-column format, a 'wide' (starred) float (`figure`, `table` etc.) must always occur at the top of a page. It cannot be placed 'here' or at the bottom. Hence the `h` specifier does nothing. `t` (or `p`) are the only effective options.

So, the only way I can see to have the paragraph come before the table and be on the same page is if the paragraph is included inside the `table*` environment.

But, if we do that, then it will default to one-column mode. So, we need to do something special to get this particular paragraph into two-column mode.

I didn't expect this to work, but it turns out that **multicol**'s `multicols` environment works quite happily inside the `table*` environment, even if the document is in two-column mode.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{supertabular,multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{multicols}
  \caption{Caption}
  \centering
  \begin{supertabular}{c c c c c}
    \hline \hline
    A & B & C & D & E\\
    \hline
    1 & a & A & D & E \\
    2 & b & B & D & E\\
    3 & c & C & D & E\\
    4 & d & D & D & E\\
    5 & e & E & D & E\\
    6 & f & F & D & E\\
    7 & g & G & D & E\\
    8 & g & G & D & E\\
    9 & g & G & D & E\\
    10 & g & G & D & E\\
    11& g & G & D & E\\
    12 & g & G & D & E\\
    13 & g & G & D & E\\
    14 & g & G & D & E\\
    \hline
  \end{supertabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2-col paragraph and 1-col table in 2-col document]

If you would like to improve the appearance of the table itself, the **booktabs** manual is a source of useful guidance. That package gives us some nicer spacing around rules of different weights, as used in professional-quality typesetting of tables.

Adding that package, we can write

```
  \begin{supertabular}{c c c c c}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D & E\\
    \midrule
    1 & a & A & D & E \\
    2 & b & B & D & E\\
    3 & c & C & D & E\\
    4 & d & D & D & E\\
    5 & e & E & D & E\\
    6 & f & F & D & E\\
    7 & g & G & D & E\\
    8 & g & G & D & E\\
    9 & g & G & D & E\\
    10 & g & G & D & E\\
    11& g & G & D & E\\
    12 & g & G & D & E\\
    13 & g & G & D & E\\
    14 & g & G & D & E\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{supertabular}
```

to produce

[image: improved table]

Adding some more 'lipsum' text, the page layout looks something like this:

[image: 2-1-2]

Note that this will not work if you want the paragraph and table on the first page of the document, as they will automatically be floated to the next page, even if they are first in the source. I'm guessing that is not required simply because people usually have at least a title first and you seem to want the paragraph to be the first thing on the page.

If you did want this as the first thing, then things are a bit more complex, but I think you could specify it in the optional argument to `\twocolumn`, removing the `table*` environment and using `\captionof` from **caption** in place of `\caption`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{supertabular,multicol,booktabs,caption}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[%
  {%
    \begin{multicols}{2}
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{multicols}
    \captionof{table}{Caption}
    \begin{center}
      \begin{supertabular}{c c c c c}
        \toprule
        A & B & C & D & E\\
        \midrule
        1 & a & A & D & E \\
        2 & b & B & D & E\\
        3 & c & C & D & E\\
        4 & d & D & D & E\\
        5 & e & E & D & E\\
        6 & f & F & D & E\\
        7 & g & G & D & E\\
        8 & g & G & D & E\\
        9 & g & G & D & E\\
        10 & g & G & D & E\\
        11& g & G & D & E\\
        12 & g & G & D & E\\
        13 & g & G & D & E\\
        14 & g & G & D & E\\
        \bottomrule
      \end{supertabular}
    \end{center}
  }%
]

\lipsum[2-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: 2-1-2 first off]

Note that `\centering` is a switch. `center` is an environment. So usually you want `\begin{center}...\end{center}` or `\centering`. In a float, the latter is usually preferable. `\center` works because the environment internally uses `\center` and `\endcenter`. But you don't normally want to use this at the document level.